# testing an in app purchase?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i developed a application with in app purchases..when user buys the subscription it gets stored on my server..after testing it few times i deleted the data from server to test it again but when i buy it the sandbox environment says u

> you already purchased this.TAP OK to download it again for free

also i have used this test account on my previous application?? does it means i will have to create a new test account for this application?? also by mistake i used this account on apple store..i read somewhere that doing this will make your test account invalid...is it true?? should i create a new account for it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For first question* - 
Since you are using the non-consumable model "you already purchased this.TAP OK to download it again for free" This is the valid behavior... StoreKit maintains the information whether you have purchased the app already or not. If you purchased already you can download data for free.

In your code, you need to check whether the data is present in the server, if it is present then don't download else download it.

InAppPurchase products are tied with the application... If there are two applications like HDversion and liteVersion... You need to create different ProductID's for inAppPurchase.

Comment: so storekit maintains the information of my test account even if i delete the data from server?? also when i test my application using test account the sandbox environment asks me to buy the product and after buying it asks me to buy the product again straightaway. Is it some problem while using test accounts or is there a problem in products request which might be getting called twice????